# Error on sending mail with attachment using Amazon AWS and PHP

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, email-attachments

I have to send mail using Amazon AWS with PHP, I am able to send simple mail but got following Error, I used many codes get from Google but still I got the same error every time.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Aws\constantly() (previously declared
>   in /path/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php:20) in
>   phar:///opt/lampp/htdocs/path/amazon/aws.phar/Aws/functions.php on
>   line 22

Code I used:-

```
require_once '/mypath/vendor/autoload.php';
include_once("SESUtils.php");

$subject_str = "Some Subject";
$body_str = "<strong>Some email body</strong>";
$attachment_str = file_get_contents("mypdf_file.pdf");

//send the email
 $params = 
  array("to" => "to@xyz.com",
  "subject" => "Some subject",
  "message" => "<strong>Some email body</strong>",
  "from" => "from@xyz.com",
  "replyTo" => "reply_to@gmail.com",
  "files" => 
  array(
  "1" => array(
  "name" => "filename1", 
  "filepath" => "/path/to/mypdf_file.pdf", 
  "mime" => "application/pdf"
  ),
  )
  );

$res = SESUtils::sendMail($params);
```

aws version:- 3.21.6
AND SESUtils.php

```
require_once('aws.phar');
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
class SESUtils {
    const version = "1.0";
    const AWS_KEY = "AWS_KEY";
    const AWS_SEC = "AWS_SEC";
    const AWS_REGION = "us-east-1";
    const MAX_ATTACHMENT_NAME_LEN = 60;

    public static function sendMail($params) {
        $to = self::getParam($params, 'to', true);
        $subject = self::getParam($params, 'subject', true);
        $body = self::getParam($params, 'message', true);
        $from = self::getParam($params, 'from', true);
        $replyTo = self::getParam($params, 'replyTo');
        $files = self::getParam($params, 'files');

        $res = new ResultHelper();

        // get the client ready
        $client = SesClient::factory(array(
                    'key' => self::AWS_KEY,
                    'secret' => self::AWS_SEC,
                    'region' => self::AWS_REGION
        ));

        // build the message
        if (is_array($to)) {
            $to_str = rtrim(implode(',', $to), ',');
        } else {
            $to_str = $to;
        }

        $msg = "To: $to_str\n";
        $msg .= "From: $from\n";

        if ($replyTo) {
            $msg .= "Reply-To: $replyTo\n";
        }

        // in case you have funny characters in the subject
        $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, 'UTF-8');
        $msg .= "Subject: $subject\n";
        $msg .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n";
        $boundary = uniqid("_Part_".time(), true); //random unique string
        $boundary2 = uniqid("_Part2_".time(), true); //random unique string
        $msg .= " boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
        $msg .= "\n";

        $msg .= "--$boundary\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n";
        $msg .= " boundary=\"$boundary2\"\n";
        $msg .= "\n";
        $msg .= "--$boundary2\n";

        $msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
        $msg .= "\n";
        $msg .= strip_tags($body); //remove any HTML tags
        $msg .= "\n";

        // now, the html text
        $msg .= "--$boundary2\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
        $msg .= "\n";
        $msg .= $body; 
        $msg .= "\n";
        $msg .= "--$boundary2--\n";

        // add attachments
        if (is_array($files)) {
            $count = count($files);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $msg .= "\n";
                $msg .= "--$boundary\n";
                $msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
                $clean_filename = self::clean_filename($file["name"], self::MAX_ATTACHMENT_NAME_LEN);
                $msg .= "Content-Type: {$file['mime']}; name=$clean_filename;\n";
                $msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$clean_filename;\n";
                $msg .= "\n";
                $msg .= base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['filepath']));
                $msg .= "\n--$boundary";
            }
            // close email
            $msg .= "--\n";
        }

        // now send the email out
        try {
            $ses_result = $client->sendRawEmail(
                    array(
                'RawMessage' => array(
                    'Data' => base64_encode($msg)
                )
                    ), array(
                'Source' => $from,
                'Destinations' => $to_str
                    )
            );
            if ($ses_result) {
                $res->message_id = $ses_result->get('MessageId');
            } else {
                $res->success = false;
                $res->result_text = "Amazon SES did not return a MessageId";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $res->success = false;
            $res->result_text = $e->getMessage().
                    " - To: $to_str, Sender: $from, Subject: $subject";
        }
        return $res;
    }

    private static function getParam($params, $param, $required = false) {
        $value = isset($params[$param]) ? $params[$param] : null;
        if ($required && empty($value)) {
            throw new Exception('"'.$param.'" parameter is required.');
        } else {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    /** Clean filename function - to be mail friendly **/
    public static function clean_filename($str, $limit = 0, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
        if( !empty($replace) ) {
            $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
        }

        $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
        $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\/_| -]/", '', $clean);
        $clean = preg_replace("/[\/| -]+/", '-', $clean);

        if ($limit > 0) {
            //don't truncate file extension
            $arr = explode(".", $clean);
            $size = count($arr);
            $base = "";
            $ext = "";
            if ($size > 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
                    if ($i < $size - 1) { //if it's not the last item, add to $bn
                        $base .= $arr[$i];
                        //if next one isn't last, add a dot
                        if ($i < $size - 2)
                            $base .= ".";
                    } else {
                        if ($i > 0)
                            $ext = ".";
                        $ext .= $arr[$i];
                    }
                }
            }
            $bn_size = mb_strlen($base);
            $ex_size = mb_strlen($ext);
            $bn_new = mb_substr($base, 0, $limit - $ex_size);
            // doing again in case extension is long
            $clean = mb_substr($bn_new.$ext, 0, $limit); 
        }
        return $clean;
    }

}
class ResultHelper {
    public $success = true;
    public $result_text = "";
    public $message_id = "";
}
```

Comment: What version of `aws.phar` you're using? Also, it would be helpful if you share the code for `sendMail` in `SESUtils`.

Comment: aws version:- 3.21.6, please see the above for SESUtils.php

Answer (score 1):

I had this error about redeclaring `constantly()` and the problem was resolved in our code by simply changing:

```
include('/PATH/TO/aws-sdk-3/aws-autoloader.php');
```

to

```
include_once('/PATH/TO/aws-sdk-3/aws-autoloader.php');
```

Maybe that will help you or the next person to Google this error message!

Answer (score 0):

This is just namespacing. Look at the examples for reference - you need to either use the namespaced class or reference it absolutely, for example:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```